Java Spring boot HikariPool :JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [Connection is not available, request timed out]
I am getting Unable to acquire JDBC Connection frequently when try to fetch or save data to a table.
Exception in thread "Thread-215" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
Exception in thread "Thread-215" org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:601)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385)

DBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 180000ms
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94)

In my Spring Boot application, I am trying to get data and save them from Postgres SQL My application query the DB and save the results inside a while loop.
The while loop may execute more than 500 times dependents on the table count
int count = programRepository.countBlackoutPending();
while (count>0) {
  .....
  new Thread(() -> {
     ........
      ProgramEntity programList = ProgramRepository.findAllByID(); //Querying the program table 

      programList.foreach(program: ProgramList){
                        // Some updation logic (API calling)
       programRepository.save(program); // Saving the updated data into the program table
      }
  }
}

My project configuration
Data Base: Postgres
Connection: Hikari Connection Pool
Application.properties
spring:
   datasource
      Hikari:
         maximum-pool-size: 150
         connection-timeout: 180000

I have tried to increase the maximum-pool-size to 300 and adding @Transactional annotation to the class also not helping, getting same exception when try with the config
Please help me on the issue

Spring Boot does not read the configuration property named Hikari.maximum-pool-size.  It reads the spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size property.

@ChinHuang, I have given a code snippet only, I was edited the question with actual application. Properties how its looks like, please check
